# Como salvar figura no Python com matplotlib?

Tags: python, anaconda

Qualquer figura que tento salvar no Jupyter Notebook salva um arquivo em branco, que tipo de erro pode estar ocorrendo, visto que não acusa nenhum erro?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data1 = [10,5,2,4,6,8]
data2 = [ 1,2,4,8,7,4]
x = 10*np.array(range(len(data1)))

plt.plot( x, data1, 'go') # green bolinha
plt.plot( x, data1, 'k:', color='orange') # linha pontilha orange

plt.plot( x, data2, 'r^') # red triangulo
plt.plot( x, data2, 'k--', color='blue')  # linha tracejada azul

plt.axis([-10, 60, 0, 11])
plt.title("Mais incrementado")

plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("eixo horizontal")
plt.ylabel("Eixo y")
plt.show()
plt.savefig('teste.png', format='png')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você faz `plt.show()`, a figura é zerada pra preparar outro gráfico. Assim, chamar `savefig` resulta na imagem em branco que você obteve.

Você tem duas opções:

- Chamar `savefig` antes de `show`:

  ```
  plt.savefig('teste.png', format='png')
  plt.show()
  ```

.

- Usar `plt.gcf()` (de "get current figure") pra salvar seu gráfico em uma variável, e salvá-la a qualquer momento.

  ```
  fig = plt.gcf()
  plt.show()
  fig.savefig('teste.png', format='png')
  ```

Comment: Agora sim, obrigado. Uma outra dúvida, tem como aumentar a área que esta sendo salva?,Por que em outra figura a legenda esta sendo cortada quando a salvo.